# CUDA: please help me to find error in my code

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

There's code, that uses GPU:

```
__global__ void gpu_process(float* input, float* weights, float* output, int psize, int size)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if(i < psize && j < size)
        output[j] += input[i] * weights[i * size + j];
}
void process(float* input, float* weights, float* output, size_t psize, size_t size)
{
    float* in_d, *w_d, *out_d;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&in_d, psize * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&w_d, psize * size * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&out_d, size * sizeof(float));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        output[i] = 0;
    cudaMemcpy(in_d, input, psize * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(w_d, weights, psize * size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(out_d, output, size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    int rx = psize, ry = size, block_x = min((int)psize, 32), block_y = min((int)size, 32);
    dim3 dimBlock(block_x, block_y);
    dim3 dimGrid(ceil(float(rx) / block_x), ceil(float(ry) / block_y));
    gpu_process<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(in_d, w_d, out_d, psize, size);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(output, out_d, size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(in_d);
    cudaFree(out_d);
    cudaFree(w_d);
}
```

There's code, that do the same thing, but uses only CPU:

```
int blockIdxx, blockIdxy, blockDimx, blockDimy, threadIdxx, threadIdxy;
void cpu_process(float* input, float* weights, float* output, int psize, int size)
{
    int i = blockIdxx*blockDimx + threadIdxx;
    int j = blockIdxy*blockDimy + threadIdxy;
    if(i < psize && j < size)
        output[j] += input[i] * weights[i * size + j];
}
void process(float* input, float* weights, float* output, size_t psize, size_t size)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            output[i] = 0;
    int rx = psize, ry = size, block_x = min((int)psize, 32), block_y = min((int)size, 32);
    blockDimx = block_x;
    blockDimy = block_y;
    int gridDimx = ceil(float(rx) / block_x), gridDimy = ceil(float(ry) / block_y);
    for(blockIdxx = 0; blockIdxx < gridDimx; blockIdxx++)
        for(blockIdxy = 0; blockIdxy < gridDimy; blockIdxy++)
            for(threadIdxx = 0; threadIdxx < blockDimx; threadIdxx++)
                for(threadIdxy = 0; threadIdxy < blockDimy; threadIdxy++)
                    cpu_process(input, weights, output, psize, size);
}
```

Why CPU variant works correctly but GPU variant returns garbage in output? What differs in

Version of cuda-toolkit: 4.0

OS: Debian GNU/Linux, cuda installed from it's repositories.

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M.

Comment: Add error checking to your CUDA code - every API call returns a status. Check them.

Comment: Off the top of my head I'd say that the GPU version is a concurrency car crash: All the threads which compute the same value `j` access the same memory in an unspecified order. How can this work? A well-designed GPU call would have each tread only access data that's unique to the pair `(i,j)`.

Comment: I tried to add error checking. No errors.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I'll try to fix this problem.

Comment: @KerrekSB you are right.

Comment: Also note that your blocks are *at least* 32x32, which is 1024, but in all current CUDA versions you can have *at most* 1024 threads per block!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cudaThreadSyncronize is deprecated and should not be used, instead use cudaDeviceSyncronize, check the error codes of these, since they will return an error if a thread has failed. These also block all code thereafter until the task is completed, so you could also add some timing code inbetween to find bottlenecks.